# GAE/J Memcache : Cannot use as a key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached, apache-commons-collection

The [GAE doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview) said:

```
Keys and values can be of any Serializable type or class
```

I use [MultiKey](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/keyvalue/MultiKey.html) as the key but after update my app, it gives me exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot use as a key: 'MultiKey[class com.xx.xx.xx, Key<?>(Domain("xxx.com")/AppUser(2001)), -1, {}, [-lastModified, ]]'
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.makePbKey(AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java:251)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.doGet(AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java:294)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.get(AsyncMemcacheServiceImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheServiceImpl.get(MemcacheServiceImpl.java:49)
```

[MultiKey](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/keyvalue/MultiKey.html) is from apache commons-collections, which did implement Serializable

```
public class MultiKey
extends java.lang.Object
implements java.io.Serializable
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

EDIT, the code is like below:

```
MemcacheService ms = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
MultiKey key=new MultiKey(xx, xx, xx...);
ms.put( key, value );
...
```

Comment: Any other details? For example: code?

Comment: The code is pretty straightforward, see my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i got the idea, below is how gae serialize the key, it just write the object to byte array, so if one of the objects contained in the key(MultiKey in my situation) did not implement Serializable, this method will not work and throw exception, which is just my case.

```
     } else if (value instanceof Serializable) {
          flags = Flag.OBJECT;
          ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
          objOut.writeObject(value);
          objOut.close();
          bytes = baos.toByteArray();
     }
```